# Hey there! I need you help. I successfully installed PostgreSQL but failed while opening pgAdmin 4. I keep getting this message, don't know what to do

Tags: windows, pgadmin-4

I need you help.
I successfully installed PostgreSQL but failed while opening pgAdmin 4.

I keep getting this message, don't know what to do

[Whenever I try to open pgAdmin4 I get this...]

[image: 1]

Comment: Make sure that those paths are leading to the correct location.

Answer (score 0):

Remove all data from below location.
C:\Users%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\pgAdmin

Make sure your hidden files are visible from setting.